# How to override the models in models.js in pos odoo13

Tags: python, odoo-13

How to add a domain to the following model and load it at the point of sale startup.

```
{
    model:  'res.partner',
    label: 'load_partners',
    fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat',
             'phone','zip','mobile','email','barcode','write_date',
             'property_account_position_id','property_product_pricelist'],
    loaded: function(self,partners){
        self.partners = partners;
        self.db.add_partners(partners);
    },
}
```

Comment: Hi. You probably want to expand your question to include more relevant details. If your question can be summarized in one line - there's probably not enough information for anyone to help you - or the issue is so trivial that it can probably be solved by a simple search online (generally speaking).

Comment: Hi, sadly this question is still quite unreadable. There's a "blockquote" thing randomly there, just a big data blob. Please read through [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [load_models](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js#L1255) function of `point_of_sale.models` to load `res.partner` model, (You can find many models using domain in the original models file):

```
odoo.define('my_module.partners', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

    models.load_models([{
        model:  'res.partner',
        fields: ['name','street','city','state_id','country_id','vat', 'phone','zip','mobile','email','barcode','write_date', 'property_account_position_id','property_product_pricelist'],
        domain: function(self){ return [['company_id', '=', self.config.company_id[0]]]; },
        loaded: function(self, partner) {}
    }]);
});
```

**domain**: *`[domain|function]` the domain that determines what models need to be loaded. `Null` loads everything*.

***Edit:***

You can access `models` using `models.PosModel.prototype.models`, you will also need to override `prepare_new_partners_domain` method.

***Try the following example:***

```
var _super_pos_model = models.PosModel.prototype;
var _models = models.PosModel.prototype.models;

var _domain = [['id', '<=', 3]];
// partner model is the fifth element in models (index==4)
_models[4]['domain']  = function(self){ return _domain; };

models.PosModel = models.PosModel.extend({
     prepare_new_partners_domain: function(){
        var domain = _super_pos_model.prepare_new_partners_domain.apply(this, arguments);
        domain.push(..._domain);
        console.log("domain", domain);
        return domain;
    },
});

console.log("models", models.PosModel.prototype.models);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I already try this but it not work .It only work when i close commend res.partner model in original pos models.js.

Comment: If I understand, it work only if you add the code to the original `model.js` file?

Comment: Sure. I want to override this in my custom module.

Comment: Ok, I thought you need to load a new model. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to override loading models on POS

```
var pos_models = require('point_of_sale.models');

var _pos_super = pos_models.PosModel.prototype;
pos_models.PosModel = pos_models.PosModel.extend({
    initialize: function(session, attributes) {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < this.models.length; i++){
            if (this.models[i].model == 'res.partner') {
                this.models[i].fields = ['your_fields'];
                this.models[i].domain = [['sample_column', '=', true]];
            }
        }
        return _pos_super.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.